# Flask RestPlus: Add expected headers AND model

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I'm using `@api.expect(MyModel, validate=True)` in order to validate the input json of a post request again a custom model. I've created the model with `MyModel = api.model('MyModel', {...})`.

I also want to add a required (expected) header to be handled and validated by the request. I can do this:

```
parser = api.parser()
parser.add_argument('X-Authentication', location='headers')
[...]
@api.expect(parser)
```

But how can I expect and validate a model ***and*** a header since `api.parser` and `add_argument` lets me add headers but doesn't seem to handle a "add this model as body payload" while `api.model` doesn't let me add headers?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should be able to do this using @ns.doc

@ns.doc(body=some_model, parser=some_parser)